I run my C code in VSCode, but don't get the output
In the output window I have this message: Error: there is no registered task type 'Compile'. Did you miss installing an extension that provides a corresponding task provider?enter image description hereenter image description here
I should get 2 output:


hello
hello world



Welcome, @user28165503. Your post is mostly images. Add additional details to explain the problem and expected results.
